# What is the difference between type conversion and type assertion?

Tags: go, type-conversion, type-assertion

What is the main differences between :

1. `v = t.(aType) // type assertion`
2. `v = aType(t) // type conversion`

Where should I use type assertion or type conversion ?

Comment: Also a bit off-topic but worth noting, casting generally implies some sort of runtime support, but assertions are purely a compile time construct and a way to provide the compiler hints on how you want your code to be analysed.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

A type assertion asserts that `t` (an interface type) actually is a `aType` and `t` will be an `aType`; namely the one wrapped in the `t` interface. E.g. if you know that your `var reader io.Reader` actually is a `*bytes.Buffer` you can do `var br *bytes.Buffer = reader.(*bytes.Buffer)`.

A type conversion converts one (non-interface) type to another, e.g. a `var x uint8` to and int64 like `var id int64 = int64(x)`.

**Rule of thumb**: If you have to wrap your concrete type into an interface and want your concrete type back, use a type assertion (or type switch). If you need to convert one concrete type to an other, use a type conversion.

Comment: "and t will be an aType" - Can you elaborate on that? `t` is not modified?

Comment: @nemo I think he would say `v`, not `t`

Comment: @LucianoQ: No, it's `t` not `v`. @nemo: No `t` is not modified by a type assertion or a type conversion. I strongly recommend the Tour of Go and the language spec afterwards.

Comment: @Volker thanks for the recommendation, it is good lecture! However, I still think that you meant `v` and not `t`. `t` in this case is will be some interface type, e.g. `interface{}` and after the assertion *on* `t`, the *resulting* value `v` will be of type `aType`.

Comment: @nemo. No. I mean that the dynamic type of t is aType. The type of v is uninteresting.

Comment: Yes, it is. But you never said that in the answer.

Comment: @nemo The go to reference for this stuff is the language spec and not my answer.

Comment: OK, let me try to rephrase the initial question so we stop misunderstanding each other. In your answer you wrote: "A type assertion asserts that t (an interface type) actually is a aType and t will be an aType; " . This sentence redundantly states that `t` is of type `aType`, hence why I asked whether you meant `v` in the second part of the sentence. This is also what @LucianoQ meant.  I could just edit your answer but I thought I ask to clear up any misunderstanding beforehand.

Comment: @nemo I have to admit I do not see much value in this discussion. The static type of an interface is pretty much uninteresting.

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr** `x.(T)` asserts that the dynamic value of interface `x` is `T` at run time; `T(x)` converts the type of an expression `x` to some other type.

#### Type Assertion

You know that in Go an interface is basically a method set specification, and you can assign to an interface variable any value whose type implements that method set<sup>1</sup>.

The [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) written `x.(T)` asserts that the value stored in the interface `x` is of type `T`. You use a type assertion when you want to **unbox that value**.

One of the most common uses is when you have `interface{}` and you need to retrieve the concrete value it stores. A typical example, [`Context`](https://pkg.go.dev/context#Context) values:

```
func foo(ctx context.Context) {
    s := ctx.Value("my_key").(string) // signature is `Value(key interface{}) interface{}`
    // do something with s...
}
```

It is called assertion because at compile time it is not known whether `x` actually holds the concrete type `T`, but you *assert* that it does.
 That's why the unchecked assertion `y := x.(T)` panics if `x` doesn't actually hold a `T` — you must use the comma-ok assignment `v, ok := x.(T)` to avoid it.

```
ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, "my_key", "foo")
s := ctx.Value("my_key").(int) // panic

v, ok := ctx.Value("my_key").(string)
fmt.Println(v, ok) // "foo" true
```

In addition, when `T` in `x.(T)` is an interface itself, the assertion checks that the value stored in `x` implements `T`. The outcome is the same as above.

#### Type Conversion

A [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) written as `T(x)` instead *"changes the type of an expression to the type specified by the conversion"*, i.e. changes the type of `x` to `T`. An important property of conversions is that they are **statically checked**<sup>2</sup>. An invalid conversion simply won't compile:

```
    type Foo string
    type Bar int

    a := "foo"
    fmt.Println(Bar(a)) // cannot convert a (type string) to type Bar
```

The main condition for a conversion to be valid is [assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) between the types involved, but there's several more, including conversions between numerical types, strings and byte/rune slices, directed channels, slices and array pointers, etc.

In simple terms, you use a conversion when you already know what are the types involved, and simply want to change one to the other:

```
b := []byte("foo")  // converts string literal to byte slice
```

---

Notes:

1: more formally, when the value's method set is a superset of the interface method set; this is also why the empty interface `interface{}` can hold any value, because any set is a superset of an empty set.

2: type assertions are also checked at compile time when the type `T` in `x.(T)` does not implement the interface. In practice, this won't help you catch errors when `x` is `interface{}` since all types implement it.